# Unity3d, UI проблема с некликабельными кнопками

Tags: unity3d, ui

Сделан UI на юнити, раньше все работало нормально, без проблем.

После последнего запуска(ничего не менял) - все элементы UI стали некликабельны. Сохранил UI и перенес на другую сцену - все работает. Как мне исправить это в текущей сцене?

**Обновление**

Проблема в том, что я собрал UI, все прекрасно работало до вчерашнего дня.(Каждая кнопка была кликабельна), сейчас же, по непонятным мне причинам, после запуска сцены - я не могу нажать ни на одну кнопку, точнее они просто некликабельны. Соответственно я хочу, что бы все было кликабельно. Ошибку найти не могу, ведь ничего не менял. Все остальные объекты на сцене - работают нормально, как раньше.

Comment: @KromStern Это комментарий, внесенный в вопрос.

Comment: Можешь скриншоты приложить, в самом инспекторе и иерархии

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте объект EventSystem удалить и по новой добавить. Если события не обрабатываются скорей всего дело в нем

Comment: Использую обычный OnClick(). Удалил событие, добавил заново, но ничего не изменилось, как будто что-то мешает кликать. ТАкое обычно, если сверху лежит какой-то UI объект с высшим приоритетом, но такого нету.

Comment: а проектом не поделитесь в приближении, так сложно догадки строить

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего уже поздно с ответом, но все таки пусть будет, ибо я столкнулся с той же проблемой и понятного новичку ответа не увидел.
Однако немного покопавшись понял.
Как выше отметили, нужно просто добавить обработчик событий EventSystem(лежит в разделе UI, если что). После добавления оного кнопки начинают обрабатываться корректно. Ниже есть скрин как он выглядит.

Comment: Нет не поздно! Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю еще один вариант, почему может не работать кнопка.
На канвасе должен быть компонент `GraphicRaycaster`.

Answer (score 0):

Если у канваса RenderMode: World Space, то надо выбрать камеру (Event Camera)

Answer (score 0):

Возможноя проблема: в свойствах кнопки компонент `image` посмотрите, стоит ли галочка на *Raycast Target*. Если да, то уберите.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кому не помогло из выше перечисленного. У меня была проблема в том, что дочерние объекты кнопки или же сама кнопка на слое дефолтном, а надо UI. Ошибка глупая, но фатальная.